# Macbook Pro Wi-Fi intermittently won't turn on after sleep

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-snow-leopard, macbook-pro, airport

My current generation MacBook Pro 15" (10.6.5) intermittently has problems turning the Wi-Fi (airport) on. The usual symptom happens when I:

- Sleep the machine
- Open from sleep
- Wi-Fi is off (the airport signal is blank)

I click on Airport icon → Turn Airport On. But nothing happens.

One recommended solution was to delete the "Automatic" location and create a new one and enable the Wi-Fi, or I delete the "AirPort" from the location and add it back. But neither of these resolve the problem.

I also called AppleCare and they had me delete `/Library/SystemConfiguration` and restart, but that hasn't solved the problem. I have to reboot, which is very painful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be hardware related.

The apple store sent my machine off to a shop where they replaced the motherboard and airport card and that did the trick.

Comment: Please accept your answer. Tis question was just bumped to the front page as the system considers it unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

I pulled a PC move and "forced" shut down (held the power button down until it the machine turned off) and BOOM, Wi-Fi was back in action after the next boot.

Not condoning this computer taboo, but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a well known issue (http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2644274&start=0&tstart=0) with no tried and true solution. I'm running a late 2008 unibody macbook pro with 10.6.6 and I am *not* seeing this problem, so have you considered the 10.6.5 -> 10.6.6 update?

Comment: Check the version numbers in your post. They don't make sense.

Comment: Fixed - Thanks for the pointer Daniel, it's been one of *those* days and one of *those* weeks so far.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll upgrade and see what happens.

Comment: Upgraded this morning to 10.6.6, put it to sleep and went into the office, no airport :(

Comment: Well sorry to hear it. I guess it must be something specific to current model MBPs then.

Comment: yeah I never saw this on my last model, ah well :( thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

- Go to applications - utilities - activity monitor
- make sure you are showing "All Processes" in the comboBox
- type mdns in the search field
- click the mDNSResponder process and click "Quit Process"

Don't worry, it will restart.

This should get you back up a running.

Comment: Do you have a source or explanation? DNS shouldn't affect WiFi connectivity in this way.